# Nodejs/Mongoose : query when mongoose disconnected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a nodejs app using express and mongoose:
node v8.9.4
express v4.15.5
mongoose v5.2.9

And the following code

```
var mongoose_options = {
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
    reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
    poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
    // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
    bufferMaxEntries: 0,
    connectTimeoutMS: 10000, // Give up initial connection after 10 seconds
    socketTimeoutMS: 30000, // Close sockets after 45 seconds of inactivity
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    keepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000
};

mongoose.set("bufferCommands", false);      // disable buffer
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);    // fix depreciated option in mongoose 5.2.9
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);       // fix depreciated option in mongoose 5.2.9

mongoose.connect(config.database, mongoose_options);


app.get("/status", function (req, res) {
    "use strict";
    Config.findOne({
        appname: appname
    }, function (err) {
    // si problème lors de l'interrogation de la base mongoDB
    if (err) {
        logger.log("%s | le %s est démarré mais l'accès à la base de données est impossible : %s", timestamp("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss:iii"), appname, JSON.stringify(err));
        return res.status(500).send("le " + appname + " est démarré mais l'accès à la base de données est impossible");
    }
    return res.status(200).send(functions.gen_output("success", "le " + appname + " est démarré"));
    });
});
```

In the normal case, every thing work fine. But if the mongodb connection goes down, and the node app receive a http request "/status", the request still hang for a while even i the buffer options are set to disable it.

express error handling is triggered after 30s and I got the following message on the console

```
MongoError: failed to reconnect after 30 attempts with interval 1000 ms
```

It looks like if mongoose did not use the options I had set.

If the mongodb connection keeps down and I retrie a http request "/status" I got the message in the console:

```
MongoError: Topology was destroyed
```

Could someone help me to figureout what is wrong in my code to secure my app if the mongodb connection goes down?

Comment: Topology destroyed means you are trying to use the server when it has already disconnected. You should remove some of those settings until you find something that works. Usually mongodb connections are very stable.

Comment: Hi, as the mongodb will be hosted on an other server I need to be sure that if a network outage occurs the node app will works correctly after network recovering

Comment: Any of your database calls should report errors, you want to poll this status API to see if it's down? There could be tons of reasons for your server to be down, a continuous monitoring tool would maybe be what you're looking for. Usually you can't just reconnect, the problem doesn't go away on its own.

Comment: Actually I am checking the connection state and I can monitor if the connection is down/up... But after investigation, it seems that whatever the option i set in the mongoose.connect it is never used and default mongodb drivers options are used